# Facebook API unsupported get request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am posting Open Graph actions using the PHP SDK. Randomly about 1 in 20 of these actions turns up on the wall as normal but I am unable to access or delete it through the API. Trying to do so errors with "unsuported GET request" or "unsupported delete request". These actions are thus stuck forever on the timeline unless user removes them using Facebook.

My guess is that it's an access token issue, but what cause and solution?

UPDATE

I found a bug in my code where an action was sometimes deleted twice, hence the exception. I take issue with the error code however, which is the same one returned for a host of things, most of them access token related. A simple "alias does not exist" would have saved me a lot of hair pulling.

Comment: yeah, i have the same error some times ago. "unsupported GET request" or "unsupported Graph request". It can be, if you have old token or (in my case) it was, when i try to use API without valid token.

Comment: I can however keep posting and deleting other actions, which requires a working token. Despite this there remain some deadlocked posts.

Comment: CHECK THIS:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644513/user-opted-out-of-platform-can-post-and-is-viewable-but-not-via-the-graph-api